# Piping and writing additional output to the output file

Tags: bash, wc

I want to write the output of `wc -l` to a file and before the number, I want to add the date. For example,

```
$ wc -l file.txt
25
$
```

I want to append

```
Wed Jul  8 17:30:17 +0130 2020 25
```

to another text file. Don't know how to correctly put `echo date` in
`cat file.txt | wc -l > anotherfile.txt`.

I have the `ts` command available, from the `moreutils` package.

Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to do exactly as described in your title, then you could use command grouping, ex.

```
{ printf '%s\t' "$(date)"; wc -l < file.txt; } > anotherfile.txt
```

(using `printf` here to avoid a trailing newline).

However you might want to consider using the `ts` command instead

```
wc -l < file.txt | ts > anotherfile.txt
```

At least in the `moreutils` implementation, `ts` accepts a `strftime`-like format argument so for example

```
wc -l < file.txt | ts '%c' > anotherfile.txt
```

will add a timestamp in your locale's default date and time format.

Comment: My `ts` (Linux Mint) defaults to a different format than `date`.